# Can FFmpeg record audio on Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Since `MediaRecoreder` not supports encoding to `mp3` format.
Can `ffmpeg` to record audio directly from Android audio source (how to specify this) or it only encodes one file to other format?

Answer (score 0):

You mean using Android to record audio and save it as mp3?
If so, you can code mp3 using libmp3lame. And this is very useful.
Since Android Record outputs a pcm, liblmp3lame can use pcm as input and then output mp3 data.